# ReactCSSTransitionGroup or {CSSTransition, TransitionGroup}

Tags: reactjs, animation, css-transitions, reactcsstransitiongroup, react-transition-group

I am a little confused about ReactCSSTransitionGroup. Read docs

- https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html
- http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/

In examples used: ReactCSSTransitionGroup, and single CSSTransition, in the list exemple  {CSSTransition, TransitionGroup}

So they all do same things (animation), but ReactCSSTransitionGroup looks like this

*all from doc exemples*

```
 render() {
  return (
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
      transitionName="example"
      transitionAppear={true}
      transitionAppearTimeout={500}
      transitionEnter={false}
      transitionLeave={false}>
      <h1>Fading at Initial Mount</h1>
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
  );
}
```

single CSSTransition

```
<CSSTransition
   in={showValidationMessage}
   timeout={300}
   classNames="message"
   unmountOnExit
   onExited={() => {
     this.setState({
     showValidationButton: true,});}}
  >
          *some code*        
</CSSTransition>
```

{CSSTransition, TransitionGroup} - like this

```
<TransitionGroup className="todo-list">
   {items.map(({ id, text }) => (
      <CSSTransition key={id}  timeout={500} classNames="fade">
         <ListGroupItem>
           *Some code*
         </ListGroupItem>
     </CSSTransition>
  ))}
</TransitionGroup>
```

So when I should / better to use ReactCSSTransitionGroup,  single CSSTransition or  {CSSTransition, TransitionGroup} ?

Comment: So I got it. It's no more issue

Comment: Why don't you tell it ?